# Can I lay Engineered Wood floor over curved subfloor?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, hardwood-floor, engineered-flooring

Is it ok to lay engineered wood floor over subfloor with such a dip in the middle? The existing floor is pretty even from board to board, but it does dip uniformly in the middle of the room. Would it make a difference if I were to lay the floor perpendicular to the existing boards? It's a very old house and it is structurally sound. Thanks

[image]

Comment: As in the answer usually no.  The only way for this to maybe work is if the slope to the low part was long and low enough and even, maybe a 1/2 inch(or less) over 10 feet.  The new boards will have to be parallel with the slope to the dip.

Comment: Why spend the time and money putting a nice new floor over the top of a messed up sub-floor? Since you've got it taken apart, fix the sub-floor and then make it pretty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "no" this is not a good idea.  If the subfloor is not straight and level the new flooring will not join its edges properly and you'll have gaps.

My suggestion is to clean up the mess you're showing in the photo and then level the floor after ensuring that it's not sagging.  Some pourable leveling compound is probably your best bet.

Comment: I would change level to flat.  Most flooring will not mind a straight flat slope.  Pool/snooker tables do like to be level.